# Chekbox внутри select option

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь разузнать, как можно запихнуть chekbox внутрь расскрывающегося списка(select) к каждому option соответственно. Подскажите как это можно реализовать. В какую сторону копать? Может есть плагин какой или что-то ещё. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Возможно вы ищите это? http://htmlbook.ru/html/select/multiple

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)

Пример использования:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.14/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.14/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>


<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```